# Gitlab: problems setting a public repo

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a project ready for deliver in a Gitlab project. I need to share it so I went to "Settings" option, check my project from "private" to "public" and save the changes.
I don't understand how but now my project is empty, no commits and no files.
Can anyone help me to recover it?

With 'git reflog' I can see all my commits on the console, but when I try to push it gaves me 'error 403'. I think that when I change the repositories permission, it changes the keys for access. How can I restore it?

May be pushing the files and commits to a new repo can work? I don't know how to change the commits destination.

Comment: Branches are there in the gitlab repo? Do you have a local repo? If you do have a local repo, can you push into the remote?

Comment: The repo is empty, no branches there. I have the local repo and all my files, but I can't push any file. Gives me error autentification.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the project form "private" to "public" I made it read only. With this setting GitLab doesn't allowme to push any new changes. With "public" configuration and "write and read" option enabled all my project was recovered.